# Cannot open jupyter book in the vscode with anaconda

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I've been trying to figure out all day long. I installed the anaconda 32-bit version and tried to connect with the VSCode. However, even the Python version is the same, the Jupyter Server still shows not started. Do I mess up with something?

I've seen most of the issues on gitHub, but still cannot solve the problem. Any help is highly appreciated.

```
Activating Python 3.8.5 32-bit ('base': conda) to run Jupyter failed with Error: StdErr from 
ShellExec, �䤣�� C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\tmpveyllbs2.bat �䤣�� C:\WINDOWS\TEMP\tmpigmc3qz2.bat for 
C:/Users/alex0/anaconda3/Scripts/activate && conda activate base && echo 'e8b39361-0157-4923-80e1- 
22d70d46dee6' && python c:\Users\alex0\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.python- 
2020.7.96456\pythonFiles\pyvsc-run-isolated.py c:/Users/alex0/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python- 
2020.7.96456/pythonFiles/printEnvVariables.py.
```

Comment: Did your installation path contains non-English characters?

Comment: my path is actually this `C:\Users\alex0\anaconda3`.

Answer (score 0):

Press `ctrl+,` to open setting.json, add:

```
"terminal.integrated.env.windows": {
        "PATH":""
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, but I chose to install Python only and install package independently.

Comment: that's ok, if any question occurs you can still post it and people will heip u